# Can't get application to run in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the below code put in Eclipse, and I cannot get Eclipse to let me run it as a Java application. I was able to do so on the computer on which I wrote it, but I've tried twice since on two different computers and neither has the option. I've tried to set a manual configuration to do it and I've tried `Alt+Shift+X`, but neither worked. I can run Java applications on all of these computers normally, just not this one for some reason.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Donor {

public String name;
public int age;
public double donation;

    Donor() {

    //Initialized to these values for debugging
    name = "NoName";
    age = 0;
    donation = 0;

    }

    Donor(String nameinit, int ageinit, double donationinit) {

    name = nameinit;
    age = ageinit;
    donation = donationinit;

    }

    public String toString() {

    String str = "";

    str += String.format("%s-30%i-6$%d-20", name, age, donation);

    return str;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nameinit = null;
    int ageinit = -1;
    double donationinit = -1;
    String outp = null;

    System.out.print("Enter the donor's name: ");
    nameinit = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter the donor's age: ");
    ageinit = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the donation amount: ");
    donationinit = input.nextDouble();

    Donor d = new Donor(nameinit, ageinit, donationinit);
    outp = d.toString();

    System.out.printf("%s30 %s6 %s10", "Name", "Age", "Donation");
    System.out.print("\n" + outp);

    input.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't have a single error.

Comment: It's building automatically. I disabled the automatic building and then built it manually, but I still am unable to run it as a Java application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you clicked with the right button and choose "run as" option, Java Application? It should work just fine in any environment.

Comment: When I right-click and hover over Run As, it says (none applicable).

Comment: Check in project properties if it has the facet Java Application. Right-click the project and type Facet. Are you sure it is a Java project? Try creating a new Java Project and try again.

Comment: Creating a new project did it. Thank you!

Comment: Can't see anything to do with Facets in project properties in Eclipse Helios and Juno... where am I supposed to be looking?

Comment: I was wrong about facets. Facets are only applicable when we are talking about Dynamic Web Projects using WTP.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in `eclipse sts` when selected file in project explorer is `.html` file, `run as` show `none applicable`. change to select `.java` file which contains `public static void main`, `run as` shows option `Java Application`, the problem is solved. [reference](https://coderanch.com/t/442912/ide/applicable-Eclipse-IDE)